# Query to create multiple equal records of volume distribution using duration (in terms of months)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

[Input Output Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8LBD.png)

I have a requirement where I need to have records distributed into multiple records based on the duration I get it from a linking table.

Suppose I have a volume of 100 and duration I am getting is 20 months linking table then my output should have 20 records of each 5(100/20).

Could someone please help me with the query how to do this SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WITH clause is here just to generate some sample data and, as such, it is not a part of the answer.
You can join the tables ON PRODUCT columns, limit the iterations using LEVEL <= DURATION, group the data and show the amount either as Min, Max or Avg of COST/DURATION rounded to two decimals. I put all of the data in the select list. Here is the complete code with the result.

```sql
 WITH
    t_duration AS
        (
            Select 'A' "PRODUCT", 10 "DURATION" From Dual Union All
            Select 'B' "PRODUCT",  6 "DURATION" From Dual Union All
            Select 'C' "PRODUCT",  4 "DURATION" From Dual 
        ),
    t_cost AS
        (
            Select 'A' "PRODUCT", 100 "COST" From Dual Union All
            Select 'B' "PRODUCT",  50 "COST" From Dual Union All
            Select 'C' "PRODUCT",  40 "COST" From Dual 
        )
```

```sql
SELECT
    LEVEL "MONTH_ORDER_NUMBER",
    d.PRODUCT "PRODUCT",
    d.DURATION "DURATION",
    c.COST "COST",
    Round(Avg(c.COST / d.DURATION), 2) "AVG_MONTHLY_AMOUNT",
    Round(Max(c.COST / d.DURATION), 2) "MAX_MONTHLY_AMOUNT",
    Round(Min(c.COST / d.DURATION), 2) "MIN_MONTHLY_AMOUNT"
FROM
    t_duration d
INNER JOIN
    t_cost c ON(c.PRODUCT = d.PRODUCT)
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= d.DURATION
GROUP BY 
    d.PRODUCT, d.DURATION, c.COST, LEVEL
ORDER BY 
    d.PRODUCT, LEVEL
--  
--  R e s u l t
--  
--  MONTH_ORDER_NUMBER PRODUCT   DURATION       COST AVG_MONTHLY_AMOUNT MAX_MONTHLY_AMOUNT MIN_MONTHLY_AMOUNT
--  ------------------ ------- ---------- ---------- ------------------ ------------------ ------------------
--                   1 A               10        100                 10                 10                 10 
--                   2 A               10        100                 10                 10                 10 
--                   3 A               10        100                 10                 10                 10 
--                   4 A               10        100                 10                 10                 10 
--                   5 A               10        100                 10                 10                 10 
--                   6 A               10        100                 10                 10                 10 
--                   7 A               10        100                 10                 10                 10 
--                   8 A               10        100                 10                 10                 10 
--                   9 A               10        100                 10                 10                 10 
--                  10 A               10        100                 10                 10                 10 
--                   1 B                6         50               8.33               8.33               8.33 
--                   2 B                6         50               8.33               8.33               8.33 
--                   3 B                6         50               8.33               8.33               8.33 
--                   4 B                6         50               8.33               8.33               8.33 
--                   5 B                6         50               8.33               8.33               8.33 
--                   6 B                6         50               8.33               8.33               8.33 
--                   1 C                4         40                 10                 10                 10 
--                   2 C                4         40                 10                 10                 10 
--                   3 C                4         40                 10                 10                 10 
--                   4 C                4         40                 10                 10                 10
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks as if `ntile` would do the job (at least, that's how I understood the question).

Here's a table with 100 rows (that's your "volume of 100").

```
SQL> create table test (id) as
  2  select level from dual connect by level <= 100;

Table created.
```

You'd then pass `20` (that's "duration of 20 months") to `ntile` and get the result - see the `grp` column, having 20 groups, each of them having 5 rows:

```
SQL> select id, ntile(20) over (order by id) grp
  2  from test
  3  order by id;

        ID        GRP
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2          1
         3          1
         4          1
         5          1
         6          2
         7          2
         8          2
         9          2
        10          2
        11          3
        12          3
        13          3
        14          3
        15          3
   <snip>
        91         19
        92         19
        93         19
        94         19
        95         19
        96         20
        97         20
        98         20
        99         20
       100         20

100 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT, based on new information]**

With sample tables you posted:

```
SQL> with
  2  duration (product, duration) as
  3    (select 'A', 10 from dual union all
  4     select 'B', 6  from dual union all
  5     select 'C', 4  from dual
  6    ),
  7  cost (product, cost) as
  8    (select 'A', 100 from dual union all
  9     select 'B', 50  from dual union all
 10     select 'C', 40  from dual
 11    )
```

query would look like this:

```
 12  select d.product,
 13         c.cost / d.duration as amount
 14  from duration d join cost c on c.product = d.product
 15    cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 16                                   connect by level <= d.duration
 17                                  ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 18  order by d.product;

PRODUCT        AMOUNT
---------- ----------
A                  10
A                  10
A                  10
A                  10
A                  10
A                  10
A                  10
A                  10
A                  10
A                  10
B          8,33333333
B          8,33333333
B          8,33333333
B          8,33333333
B          8,33333333
B          8,33333333
C                  10
C                  10
C                  10
C                  10

20 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.  There is slight modification in my query. Suppose I have a table and it is containing one product whose volume is 100 (I mean only having a single record) for this product. Now, my requirement is I will check this product in my linking table where my Duration is defined, lets say my duration for this product is 20 then I should get this volume equally divided into no. of buckets as my duration is. So, in this case it will be 20 buckets of volume 5 each. Hope, now it makes sense to my requirement.

Comment: Not really. Could you post test case, please? What you have now, and what you'd want to get from it?

Comment: Suppose I have one table which contains two fields product and duration: Product Duration
A        10
B        6
C        4               . Second table is having two fields as Product and Amount.                  Product Amount
A        100
B         50
C         40            .  So, I want to distribute my product amount among number of records as present in the duration. Output should be as below: Product Amount
A 10
A 10
A 10
A 10
A 10
A 10
A 10
A 10
A 10
A 10
B 8.33
B 8.33
B 8.33
B 8.33
B 8.33
B 8.33
C 10
C 10
C 10
C 10

Comment: This is, unfortunately, unreadable (as comments don't keep any formatting). Edit the original question and post that data there (formatted)

Comment: Hi, I have added one image containing inputs tables and output I am looking for. Hope this would help. Kindly, check it in my original question.

Comment: OK, got it. Have a look at edited answer, please.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, I was looking for this logic only. Many thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Just note that it is a good custom to mark useful answers (as accepted, or upvoted) so that the problem doesn't remain "unsolved".